# Windows10 で、 unix でいう sudo がやりたい

Tags: windows, sudo

`netstat -ab` を実行すると、管理者権限が必要である、と言われてエラーになりました。

```
要求された操作には管理者特権が必要です。
```

Unix でいう、 `sudo netstat -ab` みたいなことがやりたいのですが、これはどうやったら実現できるでしょうか。

---

背景: NTEmacs や msys bash などからたたきたいので、コマンドから実行したいです。また、普段こいつら環境は通常権限で実行していたいです。

---

調べたこと

[Is there any 'sudo' command for Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/42537/485243) の accepted answer を試してみました。
何かというと、コマンドプロンプトから

```
runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd
```

を実行するとよい、と記述してありました。(この時点で若干自分のほしいものと違う気がしますが、まずこれをトライしました。)
/user:Administrator のパスワードが要求されたのですが、これが何なのかわからず、実行できませんでした。（自分のログインユーザーだと、問題なくコマンドプロンプトを起動させることができるのですが、ログインユーザーなので、管理者権限はやっぱりもっていなくって、 `netstat -ab` は実行できませんでした。)

Comment: 管理者権限で実行していないコマンドプロンプトから実行すると言うことでしょうか？

Comment: その通りです。さらに言うと、コマンドプロンプトは使いづらいので msys bash や emacs からたたきたいですが、ひとまずコマンドプロンプトからできればあとは頑張れるとは思っています。

Comment: 管理者権限でのコマンドプロンプトでないが自分自身は管理者権限を持っているなら`/user:自分のログイン名` でパスワードを要求された時に自分のパスワードを入力します。 管理者権限のコマンドプロンプトというのがあると思うのでそちらをまず起動すると`runas`を使う必要はありません。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 自分のログイン名でやってみたところ、新しいコマンドプロンプトが立ち上がって、やっぱり管理者権限が足りないよ、と言われたということは、自分は管理者権限がない、ということでしょうか。。？右クリックで「管理者として実行」ができることと、管理者権限があることは違う。。？

Comment: 質問に記載されている`runas`も結局は管理者権限でコマンドプロンプトを立ち上げなおしてねってことなので、管理者権限のユーザはどのみち必要になるかと……

Comment: ああ、`cmd` を開いただけではだめです。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[mattn](https://github.com/mattn) さんの作られた Windows 用の sudo コマンドは如何でしょうか。

- Github: https://github.com/mattn/sudo
- 解説: [Big Sky :: sudo コマンド書いた。](https://mattn.kaoriya.net/software/lang/go/20170614142801.htm)

内部で `ShellExecuteEx` という API の `verb` に「Run as Administrator」を意味する `runas` を付けて起動することで、sudo のような挙動を実現しています。

Answer (score 10):

最初から管理者権限でコマンドプロンプトを実行すればよいと思いますが、Windowsで`sudo`、というかエクスプローラー上で「管理者として実行」と表示されている操作は、技術的には「**`verb`(動詞)に`runas`を指定してプロセスを開始する**」ことで実現できます。

`verb`の指定はコマンドプロンプトでは出来ませんので、PowerShellで

`Start-Process -Verb runas -ArgumentList "/K netstat -ab" cmd`

のようにコマンドレットを使用する必要があります。